# Bootstrap dismissible alert not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working out this bug for an hour now and can't seem to find any solution to it! I'm using bootstrap and i have a dismissible alert but when i click on the x to dismiss nothing happens.

Here's my div

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Still on beta stage.
</div>
```

And here is my footer where i include the js files

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/b61820ww/), make sure bootstrap js is loaded and that you aren't getting an error from somewhere else in your code (check console)

Comment: use span instead of button see whats happening

Comment: I don't see any problem, tried  https://jsfiddle.net/5k86pyab/ , verify your bootstrap's file

Comment: Well, the span worked for some weird reason without changing anything else!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <span type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></span>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Still on beta stage.
</div>
```

Comment: For previous versions of bootstrap you may need to put the container class reference into the close span href attribute instead of into the close span data-dismiss attribute.

Comment: How to auto dismiss alert after a few seconds?

Answer (score 33):

If you are using Bootstrap 5.0 it seems in the `bootstrap.js` code the `data-dismiss` selector has changed to `data-bs-dismiss`.
So I just had to change `data-dismiss="modal"` to `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` and it worked.

Comment: I was using the example from the docs for v4.0 but using v5.0....

Answer (score 6):

```html
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" style="outline: none;">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    $('.alert').alert()
  })
</script>
```

**To Fix Your Problem use the code above**

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    $('.alert').alert()
  })
</script>
```

When you click on the `X` to dismiss the alert it runs a js function called alert() and to use this function you need to **add the script-srcs given below** to your code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Bootstrap v5.1 now and according to the doc the template is

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/alerts/#dismissing

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap v.5.1
Just add **fade show** after **alert-dismissible** and add **btn-close** and **data-bs-dismiss** after class

```
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Still on beta stage.
</div>
```

Comment: Want to show how to add those classes in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have been battling this as well.  Not the most efficient way but this is how I finally resolved it for the project I am working on.
In my view, I used the following code when the condition triggered an alert.

```
messages.error(request,'Insert your error message here')
```

Then in my page template where I want to display the error.
Where 'add_data' is the page where the error displays

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <a class="close" href="{% url 'add_data' %}" data-dismiss="alert"></a>
           {{ message }}
</div>
```

The example I based this from used href="#" which goes to the top of the page when you click the X.
I just changed it to navigate back to the same page which clears the alert message.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">

                   This is just demo alert
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>

</div>

//---------script-------------------

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are successfully adding the CND to the BootStrap Javascript. You may have only included the link to the CSS link when looking under the "Getting Started" section.

Add this to your header or just before your closing body.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest update of Bootstrap that is version 5, the `data-dismiss` is changed to `data-bs-dismiss`.

Comment: The top voted answer for this question already includes this information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/). My solution was to include Bootsrtap JS, even though MDB should contain everything from Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

try using this function

```
$('.close').click(function(){
     $(".test").css("display", "none");
```

or

```
  $('.test').hide();
```

});

and declare a class in span tag

```
<strong class="test">Warning!</strong> Still on beta stage.
```

should be work

Comment: If you use display or hide, your never see the alert  again.